# how to use struts2 Iterator to iterate List<String>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

if anyone knows , how to iterate String list in jsp using  in  struts2.

(I want to display values of the list in the jsp)

Please help me..

Comment: Its always better to check official docs.It is very well documented there [Iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Java**

```
public class YourFormBean{
    private List<String> listOfString;
    //setter & getters
}
```

**JSP**

```
<s:iterator value="listOfString" status="statusVar">
  <tr> 
      <td><s:property/></td>

  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: @Ipushpe check [the document](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/iterator.html)

Comment: how to display this in TextField?

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator will iterate over a value. An iterable value can be any of: java.util.Collection, java.util.Iterator, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.Map, or an array.

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="boxtbl">
<s:iterator value="listOfString" status="strVal">
<tr>
  <td><s:property/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterate>
</table>

status  If specified, an instanceof IteratorStatus will be pushed into stack upon each iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
List<String>days=Arrays.asList("SUNDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THRSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY");
```

Jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${days}" var="days">
 <option value="${days}">${days}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.