# How to Iterate over an ArrayList of a bean class in JSP (I am using Struts2)

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a class ABC

```
class ABC
 {
   String a;
   String b;
 }
```

and their respective getters/setters. I also have an ArrayList of objects of ABC

```
ArrayList<ABC> abclist = new ArrayList<ABC>();
```

In my JSP, I am able to access the individual values by

```
var abc1a = '< s:property value="abclist.get(0).getA()"  />'
var abc1b = '< s:property value="abclist.get(0).getB()"  />'
var abc2a = '< s:property value="abclist.get(1).getA()"  />'
var abc2b = '< s:property value="abclist.get(1).getB()"  />'
```

But how do I iterate over abclist and/or store it in a JavaScript Array? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you want to iterate in JavaScript or in body tag?

Comment: Please do not raise multiple threads for same question. You may use your same [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627571/looping-through-an-arraylist-in-jsp-struts) as well.

Comment: @Aniket, In JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `abclist` must be defined in your `Action Class` or a property of your `Action Class Model`

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
    var a, b;
    <s:iterator value="abclist" var="myBean">
        a = '<s:property value="myBean.a"/>';
        b = '<s:property value="myBean.b"/>';
    </s:iterator> 

</script>
```

Comment: This needs a slight change

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link?[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784939/how-to-use-struts2-iterator-to-iterate-liststring). This will help you to iterate through the list. If you want to store your values in javascript array, please do the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var strArray = [];
</script>

<s:iterator value="abclist">
<script type="text/javascript">
    strArray.push('< s:property />');
</script>
</s:iterator>

<script type="text/javascript">
 console.log(strArray);
</script>
```

This is one kind of implementation. You can go ahead with your own ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This needs a slight change

You need to use # and then it works like a charm . Cheers!
like:

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
    var a, b;
    <s:iterator value="abclist" var="myBean">
        a = '<s:property value="#myBean.a"/>';
        b = '<s:property value="#myBean.b"/>';
    </s:iterator> 

</script>
```